# My android application can not open database for the first time after installation

Tags: android

The application works perfectly but the only problem is it can not open database after the app is installed and launched for the first time.

This is the log below from android monitor :

E/SQLiteLog: (14) cannot open file at line 30090 of [b3bb660af9]

Failed to open database '/data/data/com.programextended.ratulmahmud.accessibledictionaryoffline/databases/pe_bn_to_en.sqlite'

[Sample screenshot :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucdg8.png)

Comment: Well thats because you have error somewhere. If you want to see full explaination add stacktrace and code.

Answer (score 0):

Try launching the app when the emulator completely comes online, this might be the problem!

However launching the app with emulator it won't get connected to the internet before the app launches it takes time to connect so the app won't connect to database.